# Word for sensitivity of initial condition?

Tags: terminology, chaos-theory

Is there a word for the sensitivity of the initial conditions?

I've tried to illustrate what I mean by colouring an approximate measure of sensitivity of initial conditions in [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function#/media/File:Potential_cylinder.svg). Meaning, if the initial condition is near the left asymptote (gray, slightly exaggerated), the path of a particle in the stream will be difficult to predict (chaotic), but it will be relatively easy everywhere else (disregarding potential turbulence on the right side).

[image: rate of chaos]

So there will only be chaotic behaviour in some parts, and I was wondering if there was a word for this measure?

Comment: As a sidenote: There is no such thing as “chaotic behaviour in parts”. A dynamics is either chaotic or it isn’t. In your case, it’s not chaotic since it is not recurring.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft just connect the right and left edges :) The question will still be valid: There will only be an unstable equilibrium if the particle is in the gray area.

Comment: I do not dispute the validity of your question, hence only a comment. If you connect the right and left edges, the question arises, where the difficulty of prediction comes from. If there is nothing but a straight flow, there is no chaos, since the upper and lower half never mix. If the uncertainty arises from stochasticity from lower scales (as in real life), the dynamics is not deterministic anymore and still not chaotic. If you have turbulence, then you do have chaos, but it’s everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could say that the system has an unstable equilibrium at the point in question.